Transformer's Trainer Runtime error
I performed fine tuning flan-t5-small using peft.
here is my code
#loading dataset
huggingface_dataset_name = "knkarthick/dialogsum"

dataset = load_dataset(huggingface_dataset_name)

dataset

#loading original model

model_name='google/flan-t5-base'
original_model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained(model_name, torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16).to('cuda')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def tokenize_function(example):
    start_prompt = 'Summarize the following conversation.\n\n'
    end_prompt = '\n\nSummary: '
    prompt = [start_prompt + dialogue + end_prompt for dialogue in example["dialogue"]]
    example['input_ids'] = tokenizer(prompt, padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    example['labels'] = tokenizer(example["summary"], padding="max_length", truncation=True, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    return example

#The dataset actually contains 3 diff splits: train, validation, test.
#The tokenize_function code is handling all data across all splits in batches.

tokenized_datasets = dataset.map(tokenize_function, batched=True)
tokenized_datasets = tokenized_datasets.remove_columns(['id', 'topic', 'dialogue', 'summary',])

#peft config
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model, TaskType

lora_config = LoraConfig(
    r=32, # Rank
    lora_alpha=32,
    target_modules=["q", "v"],
    lora_dropout=0.05,
    bias="none",
    task_type=TaskType.SEQ_2_SEQ_LM # FLAN-T5
)

peft_model = get_peft_model(original_model, 
                            lora_config).to('cuda')
#train config
output_dir = f'/kaggle/working/peft-dialogue-summary-lora-training-{str(int(time.time()))}'

peft_training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=4,
    learning_rate=1e-3, # Higher learning rate than full fine-tuning.
    num_train_epochs=1,
    save_strategy="epoch",
    logging_steps=15,
     
)
    
peft_trainer = Trainer(
    model=peft_model,
    args=peft_training_args,
    train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
)

#train and error happened
peft_trainer.train()


This train process was going on to the last steps but at last such runtime error happened.
RuntimeError:
Some tensors share memory, this will lead to duplicate memory on disk and potential differences when loading them again: [{'base_model.model.decoder.embed_tokens.weight', 'base_model.model.shared.weight', 'base_model.model.encoder.embed_tokens.weight'}].
A potential way to correctly save your model is to use save_model.
More information at https://huggingface.co/docs/safetensors/torch_shared_tensors
